# Oracle SQL - Updating a value before PIVOT

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, pivot, case

Team --

I have the following code which works correctly and creates the PIVOT table results set as I'd like.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT a.APP_AUTOMATIC_NUMBER, a.LETTER_TYPE_ID, TRUNC (EXTRACT_DATE), 'Commercial' AS ACCT_TYPE
FROM [TABLE_NAME] a
WHERE EXTRACT_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-7 AND SYSDATE -4 AND a.ACTIVE_FLAG ='ACTIVE'
) t
PIVOT(
    COUNT(APP_AUTOMATIC_NUMBER) 
    FOR LETTER_TYPE_ID IN (
        1,13,9,'L13')
)
```

However, the value in the PIVOT talbe of 'L13' should be / can be collapsed together with the other 13 that's returned.  Basically 13 and L13 are the same thing.

Is there a way to UPDATE the records with L13 to 13 in my query?  I do not have rights to update the source table.  But I'm thinking there has to be a way to use CASE or some other statement to UPDATE L13 to 13 within my code itself.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend conditional aggregation rather than `pivot`: it is much more flexible than this vendor-specific syntax, and can easily accomodate your use case.

```
select
    trunc(extract_date) extract_day,
    'commercial' as acct_type,
    count(case when letter_type_id = '1' then app_automatic_number end) app_automatic_number_1,
    count(case when letter_type_id in ('12', 'L13') then app_automatic_number end) app_automatic_number_13,
    count(case when letter_type_id = '9' then app_automatic_number end) app_automatic_number_9
from table_name
where 
    extract_date between sysdate-7 and sysdate -4 
    and active_flag = 'active'
group by trunc(extract_date)
```

Notes:

- unless `app_automatic_number` may contain `null`  values, the conditional expressions would be better writen: `sum(case when letter_type_id = '1' then 1 else 0 end)`
- this query consistently treats `letter_type_id` as a string (this that's what it seems to) - even digit-only falues are surrounded with single quotes; using the proper datatype is always better than relying on implicit conversion (and avoids counter-intuitive behavior sometimes)